# Call system environment in .yaml file when using hydra core python package

Tags: python, linux, yaml, hydra-core

I want to call system environment in .yaml like below (error occur):

```
system_env1:   ${SYS_ENV_1}
```

I have tried to use the code, but it doesn't work. I don't want to call the env in python code, and it should be called in .yaml file. I also tried (it doesn't work what I expect):

```
system_env1:   $SYS_ENV_1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read the YAML 1.2 specification, or at least try to dump the Python string `"$abc"` to a YAML document file, and inspect the output. You'll see that nothing special, like escaping, is necessary for the `$`.
You stating "it should be called in .yaml file" is therefore misguided, a standard conforming parser will just load the `$` as is, even if it occurs at the beginning of a scalar.

You (or hydra-core) need to postprocess loaded data and replace string values starting with the pattern which means doing things in Python. Or you can  preprocess the text with some template expander *before* it is handed to the YAML parser. The later option is in my experience more often done, but in that case you should, IMO, not call the input a YAML file and not use the `.yaml` extension, as that obviously causes confusion.